# split column into lines (explode) in dbt with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt

I am very new to dbt, I am trying to explode a column value into rows using SQL on dbt.

I have a table sample_data:

```
| id       | content_toSplit |
| -------- | --------------- |
| 1        | [a, b, c, d]    |
| 2        | [a, v]          |
| 3        | [m, n, a]       |


|id   |output_column|
|-----|-------------|
|1    |  a          |
|1    |  b          |
|1    |  c          |
|1    |  d          |
|2    |  a          |
|2    |  v          |
```

I tried using unnest in a macro, and used the macro in my model:

Macro

```
{% macro split_column_to_row(column_name) %}
cross join unnest{{ column_name }} as output_column
{% endmacro %}
```

The Macro used in my model

```
select id, content_toSplit from {{ref('source')}}
{{split_column_to_row(content_toSplit)}}
```

But I am getting an "SQL compilation error: Object 'UNNEST' does not exist or not authorized." error. Also, I would like to get a position of each value.

I have also tried the below using SQL:

```
with unnest_column as (
  select
    id,
    content_toSplit
    from my_table, unnest(content_toSplit) as exploded_value
)
select *
from unnest_column
```

But getting "unexpected '('. syntax error line"

Comment: Could you share your SQL? The function UNNEST() does exist in PostgreSQL and it looks like this is what you need

Comment: I have edited my question with what I tried in SQL

Comment: `unnest` exists as function in Postgres but not `"UNNEST"` e.g. `select id, "UNNEST"(varchar_array) from array_test ; ERROR:  function UNNEST(character varying[]) does not exist`. Looks like something is quoting an up-cased form of the function name. Look at the Postgres log to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your macro is interpreting *unnest* as a table name since it follows `cross join` but that is just a guess without the actual generated SQL. Your SQL statement is using `unnest` improperly. It is uses as an old style (pre SQL-92) cross join. However, no join clause is necessary, just `unnest(content_toSplit) as exploded_value` in the select column list. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xfOxkwJx))

```
select id
     , unnest(content_toSplit) as exploded_value
  from sample_data 
 where id < 3;    -- needed to get your specific output
```

Caution: Please be consistent: You initially state *I have a table sample_data:* yet your SQL references `my_table`. This is a physically small question, but had it been larger, the inconsistency could actually keep you from getting an answer. Details are important.